# Why don't I get the output that I expect?

Tags: python, c

I'm finding the approximate square root of the number 25.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  float a = 25.0;
  float b = 0.0;

  while (abs(b*b - a) >= 0.01) {
    b += 0.00001;
  }
  printf("%f\n", b);
}
```

I expect b to be around 5 after the loop, can someone explain why it's showing 0?

When I write this code in Python it works correctly:

```
a=25.0
b=0.0

while abs(b*b - a) >= 0.01:
    b+=0.00001

print(b)
```

Comment: What output *do* you get?

Comment: Are you sure this program doesn't just take a very long (or possibly infinite) time?

Comment: Would it not have anything to do with the fact that `abs` returns an integer?

Comment: I get a `warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]` when compiling your code.

Comment: `abs(b*b - a)` --> `fabsf(b*b - a)`

Comment: May it is because abs returns an integer, I'll check that out thanks

Comment: `abs` python is not the same as `abs` C.

Comment: I've come to realize that @chux , I think Python isn't as strict as C

Comment: Is is not a question of strictness - they are different languages - different rules - different functionality.  If they behaved the same, then there would be no need for 2 names for the same language.

Comment: Note that this approach won't work in general, even if you fix the bug: https://ideone.com/33Jt33.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, `abs()` [doesn't do what you think it does](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Absolute-Value.html) (hint: it operates on [integers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdlib_h.htm)). Instead, use `fabsf()` from `math.h`: https://ideone.com/4HphCr

Comment: Why? For the given example with a=25 "abs(5.0*5.0 - 25)" becomes > 0 at about b=5.1 (the inner term is still evaluated as float). So while the result is not really accurate by using integer abs(), it should still yield something other than 0.